# How to replace thise .live function code with correct jquery 3.x code?

Tags: jquery

Can anybody advice me how to rewrite this .live function? .live is deprecated in jquery 3.x and above. The code does not work anymore. How to rewrite the .live({ bottom: { direction: 'down', bounce: true } }); part of this js?

Replacing with .on  does not work as there is no event i can use.
Please advice

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".photo_gallery img[title], .auto_thumb_tooltip[title]").tooltip({

   // tweak the position
   offset: [40, 0],

   // use the "slide" effect
   effect: 'slide'

// add dynamic plugin with optional configuration for bottom edge
}).live({ bottom: { direction: 'down', bounce: true } });
});
```

Moderators: Please do not close my question again if you do not understand my question. I added a comment to my previous one but you kept it closed. Very inconvenient i must say.

Comment: What did this do before it stopped working? There's no event type..

Comment: Well that is the whole point and is related to my question as i do not know how to replace this !  apparently .live() had different abilities then .on()